# How we write raw string in a custom databinding attribute?

Tags: android, data-binding, loadimage, android-binding-adapter

I write a custom attribute for load image url like this:

```
@BindingAdapter("srcCircleUrl")
fun loadCircleImage(view: ImageView, imageUrl: String) {
    loadImage(view.context, imageUrl, view, options = circleCropTransform())
}
```

when I want to set a raw string in xml, it gives me `srcCircleUrl attribute not found` error.

for example if I write something like this, it does not work:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:srcCircleUrl="https://66.media.tumblr.com/97bcd9782631f8bef87bb30e830344a6/tumblr_owxu10zbPB1tl4ciuo4_250.png"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    tools:srcCompat="@drawable/flag_iran" />
```

so, the question is, how can I give a raw string as input to a custom databinding attribute?

---

I also test these ways:

```
app:srcCircleUrl="@{https://66.media.tumblr.com/97bcd9782631f8bef87bb30e830344a6/tumblr_owxu10zbPB1tl4ciuo4_250.png}"

app:srcCircleUrl="@{`https://66.media.tumblr.com/97bcd9782631f8bef87bb30e830344a6/tumblr_owxu10zbPB1tl4ciuo4_250.png`}"
```

Comment: you can not load image by src Url with out image library conversion

Comment: try this sample one it will helps you https://mobikul.com/data-binding-part-ii-image-binding/

Comment: This method works as well when I get a string from an object for example `@{item.imageUrl}`, I use Glide for loading image in `loadImage` method

Comment: then what was the issue

Comment: @AravindV the issue is we cannot input raw string, for example, a link as input for this attribute

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to surround your string with single quotes and curly brackets like so `app:something='@{"my string"}'`.

I think this should work for you:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:srcCircleUrl='@{"https://66.media.tumblr.com/image.png"}'
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    tools:srcCompat="@drawable/flag_iran" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think U need returns with url format from data bind resource u cannot directly pass the https url to app:srcUrl

```
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
    public static void setImageUrl(ImageView view, String imageUrl) {
       Picasso.with(view.getContext())
                .load(imageUrl)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .into(view); 0));
    }

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable name="prod" type="com.webkul.example.Product"/>
    </data>
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/image"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:gravity="center"
  app:imageUrl="@{prod.img_url}"/>
</layout>
```